# Renaming ROWCOLGUID column when table has a FILESTREAM column

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

I have a table for storing document content with a FILESTREAM column, and another column which is a ROWGUIDCOL column (required when you have a FILESTREAM column).  I want to migrate this table with its existing data, into a slightly new structure as part of a code refactor so that 2 different projects can reuse code to manage their document records.

The problem is that I want to rename the ROWGUIDCOL column, so that both projects have the same column definitions for their document tables.

I can't use sp_rename because it doesn't work on ROWGUIDCOL columns.

I can't drop the existing ROWGUIDCOL column (and then add the replacement) because I get an error "A table that has FILESTREAM columns must have a nonnull unique column with the ROWGUIDCOL property."

I can't add the new ROWGUIDCOL column (and then drop the redundant original) because I get an error "Duplicate column specified as ROWGUIDCOL"

Is there any solution to this problem? Do I have to backup all the document content (the FILESTREAM column) and drop this first, then do the ROWGUIDCOL change, and then put the FILESTREAM content back in?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating the new table with a different name for the migration.  Then load with `INSERT...SELECT` (mapping columns as desired), drop the original table, and finally rename the new table to the original name.

Comment: OK, thanks...so are you confirming that I have no choice but to copy all the FILESTREAM data from one table to another?

Comment: @SimonGreen, this is the most efficient way I can think of to accomplish the refactoring.